# Не выводится результат jquery ajax по url

Tags: jquery, ajax

```js
         $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#loadtext").click(function(){
                $("#loader").load("text.html");
            });
         });

         $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#loadimg").click(function(){
                $("#loader").load("images.html");
            });
         });

          $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
                $("#loader").addClass('color');
            });
         });
         $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#loadblock").click(function(){
                $("#loader").load("https://myrusakov.ru/ #slider");
            });
         });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>NoNaMe</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="" class="block">
        <ul>
            <li>Первый комментарий</li>
            <li>Второй комментарий</li>
            <li>Третий комментарий</li>
        </ul>
        <button id="loadimg">Загрузить изображения</button>
        <button id="loadtext">Загрузить описание</button>
        <button id="loadblock">Загрузить myrusakov</button>

        <div id="loader" class="result"> 

        </div>
    </div>
     <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="common.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

cкрин выводимого элемента :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не выполняется последний запрос на `myrusakov.ru #slider` просто ни чего не выводится - почему ? что не так ?

Comment: Сходил по ссылке, не нашёл там ни одного элемента с классом `a--box`, а таких тегов как `hentry` и `aid-1830363971` в природе вообще не существует. Соответственно, селектор ничего и не вернёт.

Comment: Для полной ясности не помешает.

Comment: Во-первых, селектор должен быть точно такой, как показан `.a--box.hentry.aid-1830363971.answer`. Во-вторых, если просмотреть исходник страницы, а не DOM, то там этих данных нет, а значит они сами сформированы динамически и не факт, что jQuery.load умеет такое обрабатывать. Наконец, mail.ru не отдаёт свои данные на сторону: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: хотя само по себе не важно откуда выводить , на php спарсить я могу а вот load не даётся мне

Comment: Ребята, хватит обсуждать тему, которая невозможна средствами jQuery. load() не может обратиться на чужой сайт. Парсите на php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Средствами JavaScript или jQuery невозможно получать данные с другого домена.
Не буду повторять ответы уже на сотни таких же вопросов в данном форуме, я рекомендую почитать [эту](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0) статью, о том, почему нельзя обращаться на другой домен.